# PHP : flatten array - fastest way?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any fast way to flatten an array and select subkeys ('key'&'value' in this case) without running a foreach loop, or is the foreach always the fastest way?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => string
            [value] => a simple string
            [cas] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => int
            [value] => 99
            [cas] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key] => array
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11
                    [1] => 12
                )

            [cas] => 0
        )

)
```

To:

```
Array
(
    [int] => 99
    [string] => a simple string
    [array] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 12
        )
)
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array I think this answer will help you the most: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array/1320156#1320156

Comment: Any reason to make it "fastest"?

Comment: Any reason you didn't want to use `foreach`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
$ret = array();
while ($el = each($array)) {
    $ret[$el['value']['key']] = $el['value']['value'];
}
```

Comment: oh what an ancient operators :)

Comment: I would recomend always initializing the array iterator using `reset($array)` just before iterating that way, to avoid that another call to, e.g. `end()` would have messed with it. Lots of ways to fall for that trap...

Answer (score 3):

`call_user_func_array("array_merge", $subarrays)` can be used to "flatten" nested arrays.
What you want is something entirely different. You could use `array_walk()` with a callback instead to extract the data into the desired format. But no, the foreach loop is still faster. There's no `array_*` method to achieve your structure otherwise.

Comment: array_walk wouldn't work in itself, because it doesn't return anything except a bool (and you can't modify the key of the array).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it will help someone else, but here is a function I use to flatten arrays and make nested elements more accessible.

Usage and description here:
https://totaldev.com/flatten-multidimensional-arrays-php/

The function:

```
// Flatten an array of data with full-path string keys
function flat($array, $separator = '|', $prefix = '', $flattenNumericKeys = false) {
    $result = [];

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $new_key = $prefix . (empty($prefix) ? '' : $separator) . $key;

        // Make sure value isn't empty
        if(is_array($value)) {
            if(empty($value)) $value = null;
            else if(count($value) == 1 && isset($value[0]) && is_string($value[0]) && empty(trim($value[0]))) $value = null;
        }

        $hasStringKeys = is_array($value) && count(array_filter(array_keys($value), 'is_string')) > 0;
        if(is_array($value) && ($hasStringKeys || $flattenNumericKeys)) $result = array_merge($result, flat($value, $separator, $new_key, $flattenNumericKeys));
        else $result[$new_key] = $value;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should properly combine arrays with integer keys.  If the keys are contiguous and start at zero, they will be dropped.  If an integer key doesn't yet exist in the flat array, it will be kept as-is; this should mostly preserve non-contiguous arrays.

```
function array_flatten(/* ... */)
{
    $flat = array();
    array_walk_recursive(func_get_args(), function($value, $key)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $flat))
        {
            if (is_int($key))
            {
                $flat[] = $value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $flat[$key] = $value;
        }
    });
    return $flat;
}
```

You could use `!isset($key)` or `empty($key)` instead to favor useful values.

Here's a more concise version:

```
function array_flatten(/* ... */)
{
    $flat = array();
    array_walk_recursive(func_get_args(), function($value, $key) use (&$flat)
    {
        $flat = array_merge($flat, array($key => $value));
    });
    return $flat;
}
```